# Quickly run multiple blocks of Java code from Stack Overflow

Tags: java, offline

I'm looking for a quick way to run multiple blocks of Java code from Stack Overflow one code block at a time. Many Java questions at Stack Overflow have multiple answers, and I want to test most or all of the answers to a given question with my own data to determine if the code works or not. For the purpose of answering this question the Java code block doesn't need to be executable as is, because I can edit the code and add the first line(s) of code and their closing bracket(s) and the data so that the code block runs and gives output. Console output would be enough.

- I don't want to have to create a project each time I run a new block of Java code. I want to copy/paste a code block and run it without making a project of any kind. The reason for this is I expect to reject most of the code blocks that I try, and I don't want to clutter my system with a lot of useless projects. That rules out some Java IDEs that I know about.
- I'm not looking for an online application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## *JShell* — a REPL now bundled with Java

You may find useful the [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REPL) tool now bundled with Java 9 and later, *JShell*, defined in [JEP 222](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/222).

Use a search-engine to find many demonstrations, both written and video.

Answer (score 1):

I usally have an empty project in a folder and if i have to test sth really quick i open up the empty project.

Maybe you could try visual studio code with a java plugin. It opens up pretty fast and you can just run .java files.

Comment: I don't want to make a project. I want to run the code directly from a single file inside the application. When I'm finished running the code I want to either delete that file or save it.

Comment: you can do this with visual studio code. Click new file, paste the code into the file, save the file as java file, run the code. If the code sucked test the next one. Save the file e.g to your desktop so you can delete it easy later

Comment: That's what I want to do. I want to save the file to my desktop so I know where it is and I can delete it as soon as I'm finished with it. That way I can easily see whatever files that I'm working on, and if I'm interrupted then I can see where my files are the next time I login.

Comment: Is your problem now solved?

Comment: That's the way I want to save the files, but I asked how to quickly run them from inside the application and maybe do a little bit of basic debugging because I'm sometimes starting with just a code snippet and I need to edit the code snippet and add a few lines of code so that I can run it.

Comment: You can run them in visual studio code?

Comment: I need to be able to quickly edit the code and then run it afterwards, preferable to do both in the same GUI application.

Comment: But, you can? Create a new file on the desktop, create class name and main method, paste code into main method, hit run.

Comment: Or if you really need multiple run at the same times create for each possible solution a method and run them one after the other

Comment: I don't need to run multiple code snippets, just one at a time. Visual Studio Code has tabs so I can open a few code snippets at the same time, but I only need to run them one Java program at a time. Also it doesn't run when I click *Run*, not even "hello world". It says "Editing evolved" on the Visual Studio Welcome tab. I can edit code, but I can't run anything but Python so far.

Comment: and what else do you need?

Comment: I need to be able to quickly edit Java code and then run it afterwards, preferably to do both in the same GUI application. Maybe a little bit of debugging, mostly correcting syntax errors. I'm running 10 maybe 20 code snippets, so if it takes an hour to run each code snippet I'll never finish.

Comment: VS Code has all of that.

Comment: Even though I accepted a different answer Visual Studio Code is a good alternative to using a Java REPL, and I can run blocks of Java code in it using the *Code Runner* and *Java Run* VSCode extensions.